# I need to be able to parse an output from the pyowm library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to use the pyowm library to get the current temperature (https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm). However, when i call for the temperature in celsius it gives me an output like this : {'temp_max': 10.5, 'temp': 9.7, 'temp_min': 9.0} I need the temp data field but cannot figure out how to get it

Thanks to everyone who helps

Comment: That looks like a dictionary. Try temp_in_celsius['temp'] (assuming the return from pyowm is in temp_in_celsius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out! to get the temp from the output saved in the variable as 'n' you need to write the line `n['temp']`